# "dynamic" dropdowns in R Shiny only updating when clicked

Tags: r, shiny

I have an App which has some dropdown menus which update depending on what the user select (which location)

[image]

However, when one of the levels has an `NA` value, nothing gets displayed in the table.

[image]

I am trying to do 2 things:

1. Populate the table with the previous levels results if it has an `NA` value in a given region. So, for example in the second image it would have a table for `Alcaraz` since the `Select Zona Variable` has an `NA` in it.

I have tried doing something like `filter(str_detect(distrito, if_else(input$distrito == "NA", "", input$distrito)))` without luck. With the objective of filtering by nothing if there is an `NA` value.

2. Activate the next dropdown only when it has been clicked on. (if this should be a new question, let me know) - the idea is to make a table first for `Gipuzkoa` and only update the table if the `Select Municipio Variable` has been selected, then also do the same for the `Select Distrito Variable`. My main issue here is that the App applies all the filters and I would like to look at summary statistics and other tables first for the `Province`, then for the `Municipio`, then for the `Distrito` and finally for the `Zona` - currently my table jumps straight to the filter of the `zona`.

Data:

```
data = structure(list(purchase_price = c(207000, 65000, 62000, 2e+05, 
293000, 80000, 96500, 119500, 149999, 144000, 298000, 135000, 
310000, 285000, 269000, 120000, 595000, 355000, 96000, 490000, 
195000, 235000, 197000, 70000, 215000, 169000, 124900, 195000, 
185000, 190000, 390348, 113500, 295000, 299995, 156000, 195000, 
185000, 260000, 370000, 180000, 105000, 249000, 390000, 295000, 
86999, 219900, 264999, 56800, 179900, 150000, 145000, 168500, 
160000, 180000, 168000, 42300, 119000, 350000, 390000, 110000, 
420000, 154000, 429000, 85000, 259000, 495000, 170000, 102490, 
469000, 245000, 138000, 127000, 1390000, 320000, 420000, 292000, 
87500, 120000, 475000, 170000, 61000, 255000, 49000, 226000, 
220000, 3e+05, 30000, 265000, 330000, 220000, 220000, 139000, 
880000, 75000, 220000, 76400, 150000, 46000, 25000, 170000), 
    provincia = c("Gipuzkoa", "Valencia", "Valencia", "Valencia", 
    "Málaga", "Araba - Álava", "Tarragona", "Jaén", "Tarragona", 
    "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Alicante", "Granada", "Málaga", 
    "Barcelona", "Tarragona", "Tarragona", "Barcelona", "Valencia", 
    "Tarragona", "Castellón", "Segovia", "Alicante", "Tarragona", 
    "Málaga", "Girona", "Cantabria", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
    "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Sevilla", "Granada", "Barcelona", 
    "Barcelona", "Cáceres", "Barcelona", "Valencia", "Gipuzkoa", 
    "Santa Cruz de Tenerife", "Tarragona", "Almería", "Alicante", 
    "Granada", "Tarragona", "Toledo", "Tarragona", "Huelva", 
    "Castellón", "Albacete", "Madrid", "Girona", "Castellón", 
    "Zaragoza", "Madrid", "Alicante", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
    "Sevilla", "Castellón", "Valencia", "Málaga", "Alicante", 
    "Lleida", "Girona", "Madrid", "Alicante", "Pontevedra", "Barcelona", 
    "Illes Balears", "Málaga", "A Coruña", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", 
    "Barcelona", "Málaga", "Cádiz", "Valencia", "Barcelona", 
    "Toledo", "Castellón", "Barcelona", "Huelva", "Barcelona", 
    "Tarragona", "A Coruña", "Ciudad Real", "Illes Balears", 
    "Ourense", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Málaga", "Málaga", 
    "Córdoba", "Tarragona", "Castellón", "Valencia", "Castellón", 
    "Navarra", "Cádiz"), municipio = c("Bajo Bidasoa", "Valencia, Zona de", 
    "Valencia, Zona de", "Valencia, Zona de", "Costa del Sol Occidental - Zona de Estepona", 
    "Laguardia - Rioja Alavesa", "Tarragonès", "Campiña de Jaén", 
    "Tarragonès", "Maresme", "Maresme", "Marina Baixa", "Vega de Granada", 
    "Costa del Sol Occidental - Zona de Estepona", "Maresme", 
    "Tarragonès", "Tarragonès", "Barcelonès", "Horta Nord", 
    "Tarragonès", "Plana Baixa", "Cuéllar, Zona de", "Alacantí", 
    "Baix Camp", "Costa del Sol Occidental - Zona de Benalmádena", 
    "La Selva", "Costa Oriental", "Vallès Oriental", "Vallès Oriental", 
    "Vallès Oriental", "Maresme", "Sierra Norte", "Vega de Granada", 
    "Vallès Occidental", "Baix Llobregat Sud", "Llanos de Cáceres", 
    "Barcelonès", "La Safor", "Donostialdea - Oarsoldea", "Tenerife", 
    "Tarragonès", "Almería capital y entorno", "Alacantí", 
    "Vega de Granada", "Tarragonès", "Los Montes de Toledo", 
    "Tarragonès", "Huelva capital y entorno", "Plana Alta", 
    "Sierra de Alcaraz - Campo de Montiel", "Zona Sur de Madrid", 
    "La Selva", "Plana Alta", "Zaragoza, Zona de", "Madrid, Zona de", 
    "Vega Baja", "Barcelonès", "Bages", "Sevilla capital y entorno", 
    "Plana Alta", "Valencia, Zona de", "Costa del Sol Occidental - Zona de Estepona", 
    "Marina Alta", "Segrià", "Alt Empordà", "Madrid, Zona de", 
    "Marina Baixa", "Comarca de Vigo", "Vallès Occidental", 
    "Mallorca", "Costa del Sol Occidental - Zona de Estepona", 
    "Comarca de Ferrol", "Vallès Occidental", "Osona", "Osona", 
    "Costa del Sol Occidental - Zona de Estepona", "La Janda", 
    "Ribera Alta (Valencia)", "Osona", "Toledo, Zona de", "Plana Alta", 
    "Osona", "Huelva capital y entorno", "Vallès Oriental", 
    "Baix Penedès", "Comarca de Ferrol", "Alcudia (Ciudad Real)", 
    "Mallorca", "Comarca de Ourense", "Vallès Occidental", "Vallès Occidental", 
    "Costa del Sol Occidental - Zona de Estepona", "Málaga capital y entorno", 
    "La Subbética", "Baix Penedès", "Plana Alta", "Valencia, Zona de", 
    "Plana Baixa", "Comarca de Pamplona", "Campiña de Jerez"
    ), distrito = c("Irun", "Valencia Capital", "Valencia Capital", 
    "Valencia Capital", "Estepona", "Navaridas", "Salou", "Marmolejo", 
    "Salou", "Mataró", "Dosrius", "Benidorm", "Granada Capital", 
    "Manilva", "Dosrius", "Roda de Berà", "Roda de Berà", "Barcelona Capital", 
    "Puig", "Tarragona Capital", "Vila-real", "Marugán", "San Vicente del Raspeig / Sant Vicent del Raspeig", 
    "Mont-roig del Camp", "Benalmádena", "Anglès", "Laredo", 
    "Granollers", "Granollers", "Granollers", "Cabrils", "El Ronquillo", 
    "Cenes de la Vega", "Santa Perpètua de Mogoda", "Sant Boi de Llobregat", 
    "Cáceres Capital", "Barcelona Capital", "Barx", "Donostia - San Sebastián", 
    "Tacoronte", "Salou", "Almería Capital", "El Campello", 
    "Albolote", "Salou", "Nambroca", "Salou", "Huelva Capital", 
    "Castellón de la Plana / Castelló de la Plana", "Alcaraz", 
    "Fuenlabrada", "Riells i Viabrea", "Castellón de la Plana / Castelló de la Plana", 
    "Zaragoza Capital", "Madrid Capital", "Torrevieja", "Badalona", 
    "Castellgalí", "Sevilla Capital", "Cabanes", "Valencia Capital", 
    "Estepona", "Dénia", "Lleida Capital", "Roses", "Madrid Capital", 
    "L'Alfàs del Pi", "Vigo", "Sabadell", "Palma de Mallorca", 
    "Estepona", "Fene", "Cerdanyola del Vallès", "Vic", "Vic", 
    "Estepona", "Vejer de la Frontera", "Senyera", "Vic", "Toledo Capital", 
    "Borriol", "Santa Eugènia de Berga", "Huelva Capital", "Sant Celoni", 
    "Calafell", "Fene", "Almadén", "Palma de Mallorca", "Ourense Capital", 
    "Terrassa", "Terrassa", "Estepona", "Málaga Capital", "Lucena", 
    "Calafell", "Castellón de la Plana / Castelló de la Plana", 
    "Valencia Capital", "Onda", "Pamplona / Iruña", "Jerez de la Frontera"
    ), zona = c("Pinar - Anaka - Belaskoenea", "Els Orriols", 
    "Barrio de Benicalap", "Barrio de Benimaclet", "Parque Central", 
    NA, "Mar i Camp - Platja dels Capellans", NA, "Platja de Llevant", 
    "Cerdanyola Sud", "Can Massuet del Far", "Levante Alto", 
    "Centro - Sagrario", "Manilva Pueblo", "Canyamars", NA, NA, 
    "Vilapicina i la Torre Llobeta", "El Puig", "Llevant", "Centro", 
    NA, "Centro", "Poble", "Zona Centro Comercial Torrequebrada", 
    NA, "Zona Playa", "Lledoner", "Lledoner", "Lledoner", NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, "Casablanca", "Mejostilla", "El Poble Sec - Parc de Montjuïc", 
    NA, "Amara Zaharra - Arbaizenea", "Campo de Golf - Agua García - Juan Fernández", 
    "Platja de Llevant", "Plaza de Toros - Santa Rita", "Playa Muchavista", 
    NA, "Mar i Camp - Platja dels Capellans", NA, "Centre", "Tres Ventanas", 
    "El Grao", NA, "El Naranjo", NA, "Oeste", "La Magdalena", 
    "Recoletos", "Zona Carrefour - Urbanizaciones", "Sant Roc", 
    NA, "Encarnación - Regina", NA, "Penya - Roja - Avda. Francia", 
    "Bel - Air", "El Montgó", "Mariola", "Centre", "Embajadores - Lavapiés", 
    "Escandinavia - Cautivador", "Casablanca - Calvario", "Creu Alta", 
    "Son Serra - Sa Vileta", "Cancelada", NA, "Bellaterra", "El Sucre - El Nadal", 
    "El Sucre - El Nadal", "Paraiso - Barronal", "Vejer", NA, 
    "El Sucre - El Nadal", "Santa Bárbara", NA, NA, "La Orden", 
    NA, "Segur Platja", NA, NA, "Cala Major", "Centro", "Barri del Centre", 
    "Ca n'Aurell", "Cancelada", "Pinares de San Antón", NA, 
    "Segur Platja", "Norte", "Beteró", NA, "San Juan", "El Rocío - La Milagrosa"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"))
```

App:

```
library(shiny)

ui_update_filter_properties_location <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)

  tabPanel(
    id,
    tagList(
      tags$div(
        class = "panel-inputs",
        selectInput(ns("provinceSelect"), label = "Select Province Data", choices = c()),
        selectInput(ns("municipioSelect"), label = "Select Municipio Variable", choices = c()),
        selectInput(ns("distritoSelect"), label = "Select Distrito Variable", choices = c()),
        selectInput(ns("zonaSelect"), label = "Select Zona Variable", choices = c()),
        tableOutput(ns('filteredDataOUT'))
      )
    )
  )
}


server_update_filter_properties_location <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {


      observe({
        choices = data %>% select(provincia) %>% unique() %>% pull(provincia)

        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "provinceSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      })

      ## (2) ## The municipios are then updated to reflect the provincias selection
      observeEvent(input$provinceSelect,{


        choices = data %>% filter(provincia == input$provinceSelect) %>% select(municipio) %>% unique() %>% pull(municipio)

        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "municipioSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      })

      ## (3) ## Update the distrito dropdown depending on the muncipio selected
      observeEvent(input$municipioSelect,{

        choices = data %>% filter(municipio == input$municipioSelect) %>% select(distrito) %>% unique() %>% pull(distrito)
        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "distritoSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      })

      ## (4) ## Update the zona dropdown depending on the distrito selected
      observeEvent(input$distritoSelect,{

        choices = data %>% filter(distrito == input$distritoSelect) %>% select(zona) %>% unique() %>% pull(zona)

        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "zonaSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      })



      filteredDATA = reactive(
        filteredData <- data %>%
          filter(provincia == input$provinceSelect & municipio == input$municipioSelect & distrito == input$distritoSelect & zona == input$zonaSelect) %>%
          select(-c("provincia", "municipio", "distrito", "zona"))
      )
      output$filteredDataOUT <- renderTable(
        filteredDATA()
      )

    }
  )
}




ui <- fluidPage(
  ui_update_filter_properties_location("myFilter")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  server_update_filter_properties_location("myFilter", data)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this will meet your needs

```
library(shiny)

ui_update_filter_properties_location <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(
    id,
    tagList(
      tags$div(
        class = "panel-inputs",
        selectInput(ns("provinceSelect"), label = "Select Province Data", multiple = TRUE, choices = c()),
        selectInput(ns("municipioSelect"), label = "Select Municipio Variable", multiple = TRUE,  choices = c()),
        selectInput(ns("distritoSelect"), label = "Select Distrito Variable", multiple = TRUE, choices = c()),
        selectInput(ns("zonaSelect"), label = "Select Zona Variable", multiple = TRUE, choices = c()),
        actionBttn(ns("reset"), "Reset"),
        tableOutput(ns('filteredDataOUT'))
      )
    )
  )
}


server_update_filter_properties_location <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      filtered <- reactiveValues(DATA=data)
      
      observe({
        choices = data %>% select(provincia) %>% unique() %>% pull(provincia)
        choices = c("",choices)
        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "provinceSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      })
      
      ## (2) ## The municipios are then updated to reflect the provincias selection
      observeEvent(input$provinceSelect,{
        filtered$DATA <- data %>% filter(provincia %in% input$provinceSelect) 
        
        choices = filtered$DATA %>% select(municipio) %>% unique() %>% pull(municipio)
        choices = c("",choices)
        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "municipioSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
      
      ## (3) ## Update the distrito dropdown depending on the muncipio selected
      observeEvent(input$municipioSelect, {
        print(input$municipioSelect)
        if (sum( is.na(input$municipioSelect) )<1 | !is.null(input$municipioSelect)) 
          filtered$DATA <- data %>% filter(provincia %in% input$provinceSelect) %>% 
                                    filter(municipio %in% input$municipioSelect)
        choices = filtered$DATA %>% select(distrito) %>% unique() %>% pull(distrito)
        choices = c("",choices)
        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "distritoSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      })
      
      ## (4) ## Update the zona dropdown depending on the distrito selected
      observeEvent(input$distritoSelect, {
        if (sum( is.na(input$distritoSelect) )<1  | !is.null(input$distritoSelect)) 
          filtered$DATA <- data %>% filter(provincia %in% input$provinceSelect) %>% 
                                    filter(municipio %in% input$municipioSelect) %>% 
                                    filter(distrito %in% input$distritoSelect)
        choices = filtered$DATA  %>% select(zona) %>% unique() %>% pull(zona)
        choices = c("",choices)
        updateSelectInput(
          session,
          "zonaSelect",
          choices = choices
        )
      }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
      
      observeEvent(input$zonaSelect, {
        if (sum( is.na(input$zonaSelect) )<1  | !is.null(input$zonaSelect)) 
          filtered$DATA <- data %>% filter(provincia %in% input$provinceSelect) %>% 
            filter(municipio %in% input$municipioSelect) %>% 
            filter(distrito %in% input$distritoSelect) %>% 
            filter(zona %in% input$zonaSelect)
      }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
      
      observeEvent(input$reset, {
        filtered$DATA <- data 
        updateSelectInput(session,"provinceSelect",choices = c("",unique(filtered$DATA$provincia)))
        updateSelectInput(session,"municipioSelect",choices = c("",unique(filtered$DATA$municipio)))
        updateSelectInput(session,"distritoSelect",choices = c("",unique(filtered$DATA$distrito)))
        updateSelectInput(session,"zonaSelect",choices = c("",unique(filtered$DATA$zona)))
      })
      
      output$filteredDataOUT <- renderTable(
        filtered$DATA
      )
      
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  ui_update_filter_properties_location("myFilter")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  server_update_filter_properties_location("myFilter", data)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thanks! this almost works perfect! - certainly an improvement on what I had. How can I update the table after each dropdown - i.e. if I only select `Albacete` I would like to see all observations in `Albacete`, if I want to filter further I can go to the next level and then the table will update with those observations?